# Using superlatives for comparing two things

Tags: comparatives, superlative-degree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of the superlative when only two items are present](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5697/use-of-the-superlative-when-only-two-items-are-present)

Is it strictly incorrect to use the superlative when comparing only two things?

> i.e. I have two sisters. Mary is the
>   eldest?

Should it always be the comparative?

> i.e. I have two sisters. Mary is the
>   elder?